# C++ GUI Without "Windows Forms" or "Framework"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to create normal program with C++ in Visual Studio 2012 Express.I know there are many programs with GUI(I am not sure it is GUI or not,but I call normal programs with that).I want to create program like that.I tried to do it with VB and their windows forms.But When I gave it to my friend it needs some stupid files like pdb(I am not sure again,but it can't be opened) or it needs .NET framework. In anyway it didn't work.I want to create a program which don't need another file or program to work.

Just I want to make a simple program with Buttons,Labels,TextBoxs and it will not request another files. Just 1 exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options for pure "native code" user interfaces.

The [Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e.aspx) is the main option included with Visual Studio.

Otherwise, you can go to 3rd party options.  [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) is a very nice option, if you're willing to install it, and provides a much nicer development model (in my opinion) for rich user interfaces.

That being said - if you already have something working using Windows Forms, having your friend install the .NET Framework is far simpler than rewriting an entire code base just to avoid it.  It's very difficult to remove ALL dependencies on libraries - though having a native UI will potentially simplify the deployment.

Comment: I searched for Qt,but it needs another program like Net Framework,and its name is msvc (or mingw) runtime.I Dont Need Any Program Like That.I Saw There is Billions of Programs That Needs Nothing and It Have Buttons,Labels,TextBoxs and Etc.I Need an To Create an Program With Buttons That Doesnt Require any Other Runtime,Library.

Comment: The other option of course is not using any library at all, and just make some Win32 calls. More legwork, but using third-party solutions isn't the *only* way to do it.

Comment: @Huseyn26 You can statically link in Qt of course, and you should always statically link libc (msvc) on Windows (because MS doesn't ship it...).

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to use the WINAPI

Comment: -1: If I were new to programming (or at least Windows programming), all I could do with this answer would be googling "WINAPI". I don't think it's (a) substantial enough or (b) helpful enough to be an answer - it's a comment at best.

Comment: Let's say I don't know what WINAPI is and this guy (let's call him jason) wants me to learn how to use the WINAPI, the first thing I would do is looked up what it is and then learn how to use it.